# C# where keyword

Tags: c#

In the following piece of code (C# 2.0):

```
public abstract class ObjectMapperBase< T > where T : new()
{
    internal abstract bool UpdateObject( T plainObjectOrginal,
                                         T plainObjectNew,
                                         WebMethod fwm,
                                         IDbTransaction transaction );
}
```

Inheritor example:

```
public abstract class OracleObjectMapperBase< T > : ObjectMapperBase< T > where T : new()
{
    internal override bool UpdateObject( T plainObjectOrginal,
                                         T plainObjectNew,
                                         WebMethod fwm,
                                         IDbTransaction transaction )
    {
        // Fancy Reflection code.
    }
}
```

What does the `where` keyword do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it is a constraint for generics

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

so the new() constraint says it must have a public parameterless constructor

Answer (score 9):

It specifies [a constraint on the generic type parameter `T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

The `new()` constraint specifies that T must have a public default constructor.

You can also stipulate that the type must be a class (or conversely, a struct), that it must implement a given interface, or that it must derive from a particular class.

Comment: I think in this case, it specifies that `T` must have a public no-arg constructor.

Comment: @Frustrated - indeed: I've expanded on my original ridiculously terse answer. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The where clause is used to specify constraints on the types that can be used as arguments for a type parameter defined in a generic declaration. For example, you can declare a generic class, MyGenericClass, such that the type parameter T  implements the IComparable interface:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T:IComparable { }
```

In this particular case it says that T must implement a default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). It means that the generic type `T` must implement a zero parameter constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The Where keyword is basically a constraint on the objects the class can work on/with.

taken from MSDN "The new() Constraint lets the compiler know that any type argument supplied must have an accessible parameterless constructor"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It means the T has to have a public default constructor.