# Understanding some C# code

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures

I was reading one of the thread on this site only and I saw some unusual class definition which I was not able to understand that well. Can somebody please explain me what this definition mean?

```
public class Node<T> where T : class
{     
  public Node<T> Next { get; set; }    
  public T Value { get; set; }     
  public Node(T value)     
  { 
    Next = null;
    Value = value;    
  } 
}
```

especially where it says

```
public class Node<T> where T : class
```

Comment: [Generic Type Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# where keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774041/c-where-keyword)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a Generic class definition with a generic parameter T with a constraint that T has to be class (reference type).

It essentially means, when you create an instance of Node, you can do

```
new Node<String>(someStringVar)
```

but you cannot do

```
new Node<int>(someIntVar)
```

Answer (score 3):

It defines `Node` as a [generic class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) where the `T` generic type is [constrained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) only to reference types.

Answer (score 3):

`where T : class` means that T can't be a `struct` type (including primitive types like `int`).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a linked list node where the node can be of any class.  T is a specifier for a generic and the where T : class portion specifies the conditions for the generic.  In this case, T must be a class.

Answer (score 1):

This is called generics

```
where T : class
```

means that the type you supply must be a class, you cannot use primitive types. (e.g < int >)

This is defining an object called `Next` of type `Node<T>`. If the type `Size` is supplied when creating an instance of this class it means this property will be `Node<Size>`.

```
public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
```

And this:

```
public T Value { get; set; }
```

Would be the same as

```
public Size Value { get; set; }
```

**[See generics on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)**

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a heloful comment.

Comment: @Californicated the act of up voting already means `thanks` :P And make sure to accept the answer that answers your question, if any. With the check (`√`) under the vote options.

Answer (score 1):

The `T` inside the brackets is the generic type parameter. I suggest you read [the introduction on genericity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topica) for an explanation of the advantages and needs of it.

Comment: Thank you so much the aticle was really helpful.:).

Answer (score 0):

`T` is a generic type argument.  The definition is specifying a constraint where `T` can only be a `class`, not a `struct`.